# Vue-js library that allows horizontal swipe feature with animation but also allows vertical scrolling on the same components

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am creating a Tinder-esque UI where users can swipe left and right. I am using vue-interact library to have a swipe animation on the component.

Link to library: https://vue2-interact.netlify.com/

I had to disable interaction on y axis to disable swipe vertically. Since, I am creating UI for mobile screen, the swipeable component can get longer the screens and I cannot scroll it vertically. If I enable interaction on y axis , I can only drag the component vertically, not properly scroll it.

I tried vue-touch

Link: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-touch

It allows vertical scrolling but the swipe doesn't have animation. Is there a library which can offer both?

Comment: If anyone wants to create same UI, I used pan option in vue-touch to record the touch movements and transform my components. I had to override touch-action to pan-y for v-touch component to enable vertical scrolling.